# PHP variable inside sql table entry

Tags: php

I have a database entry that look like this:

```
ID  Name Content
1   Adam   is in $school
2   Mark   is in $house
```

SQL query used to load `ID 1` for example:

```
$query = "SELECT id,content from db WHERE id=1";
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$content);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $id= $id;           
            $content = $content;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Now I include another file which contains the following variables:

```
$school = "Bla bla bla";
$house = "bla bla bla";
```

My issue is when I call the SQL query it loads the variable as text; I want it to replace with the variables that I include.

Regards

Comment: i belive you might be looking for [variable variables `$$`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). from them to work i would think you wouldn't store the `$` in your database

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you want the plain text string `is in $school` pulled from your database to be replaced with `is in Bla bla bla`?

Comment: If you want to replace a value inside a string by another value, why wouldn't you simply use `str_replace(...)` ?

Comment: @icecub yes exactly

Comment: @Memor-X, I do save variables inside my DB so using $$ was not helpful, It did not worked in my case.